# What is the not subset symbol

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

I am looking for the "not subset" symbol I see in my maths textbook. Wheres that?

[image]

In Lyx, I dont see it ... Same **[here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX:Symbols)** under relations

Answer (score 58, accepted):

As always, [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) is a great help here, or even the [Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive). You are looking for `\not\subset`:

```
B \not\subset A
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

You can use `\not\subset`, or `\not\subseteq`, or `\nsubseteq` (requires the `amssymb` package):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[ A \not\subset B\qquad A \nsubseteq B\qquad A \not\subseteq B \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The question [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/3954) could be helpful for you in a similar situation.

Answer (score 7):

Simply use `$B \not \subset A$`:

[image: Subset]

`\not` can create negations of many relations. `=)`